# Re-order subviews in a full view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

- I have a view which has 3 subviews in it which are **stacked**
- Each subview is associated with a button
- On button event, I remove all subviews and then
- I add the relevant subview

However, removing and adding subviews create a performance problem

So, I was hoping to re-order subviews on button press rather than removing them.

How can I re-order stacked subviews?

Comment: By "stacked" do you mean those three subviews are nested? Or do you mean they're part of a `UIStackView`?

Comment: So they all have the same superview?

Comment: no...on top of each other...parent view is same for all subviews...meaning they all have same superview

Comment: UIView class has "subviews" method and return an Array. you can edit this array to re-order the subviews in a View

Comment: No, you cannot modify a view's `subviews`, which is a read-only property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reorder subviews by calling the following two methods:

```
parentView.bringSubviewToFront(subview)
```

or

```
parentView.sendSubviewToBack(subview)
```